# Finding The number of Divisors in a given number?

Tags: perl, loops, duplicates, output, repeat

I have created a Perl program to calculate the amount of divisible numbers in numbers **3** to **10**.

Example: the number 6 has **4 divisors** 1, 2, 3 and 6.

This is how the program is suppose to work:

The program will calculated the number of divisors of **3** it will then print it to the **report.txt** file. Next, it will move on to calculate the number of divisors of **4** and print it to **report.txt**. The program will do this until it has calculated to the number **10** then it will close the program.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $num = 2; # The number that will be calculated
my $count = 1; # Counts the number of divisors
my $divisors; # The number of divisors

my $filename = 'report.txt';

open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!"; # open file "report.txt"

for (my $i=2; $i <= 10; $i++) {  

        while( $num % $i == 0) { # Checks if the number has a remainder.
            $num++; # Adds 1 to $num so it will calculate the next number.
            $count++; # counts the number of divisible numbers.
            $num /= $i; # $num = $num / $i. 
        }

    $divisors = $count; # The number of divisors are equal to $count.
    print $fh "$divisors\n"; # The output will be repeated..
}

close $fh # Closes the file "report.txt"
```

I think the problem is that the for-loop keeps repeating this code:

```
print $fh "$divisors\n";
```

The output is:

```
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
```

but, I'm not sure exactly what I am missing.

Comment: "the amount of divisible numbers"? All numbers are divisible. It is hard to tell from your code and from your description what it is you mean for your code to do, or why you are dissatisfied with the output of `2`.

Comment: Also, please explain why you think your code works "great". As far as I can see, after the first iteration, your code is stuck repeating the exact same result, no matter what numbers you put into it, because `$num % $i == 0` will never be true once you set `$num` to `1.5`, which happens in the second iteration. `2 /= 3`

Comment: Are you trying to find prime numbers? i.e. those numbers where the number of divisors is two

Comment: Your algorithm is trying to use `$num` for two different jobs at the same time, and therefore is failing both jobs. You also don't reset `$count` for each new time around the `for` loop.  Roughly speaking, your code doesn't do anything like what you want it to do.  (`2%2 == 0` so `$num` is set to first 3 then 1 and `$count` is set to 2; thereafter, 1%x != 0 so `$num` stays at 1, and `$count` stays at 2, which is why you get 2 printed for every value.)

Comment: Of course since "The code runs great", then the solution is:  `my %seen; ..... print $fh $divisor unless $seen{$divisor}++;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your variables meaningful names.  This helps in both making your code self-documenting, but also in that it helps you recognize when you're using a variable incorrectly.  The variable name `$i` doesn't communicate anything, but `$divisor` says that you are testing if that number is a divisor.

As for why your code is looping, can't say.  Here is a reformatted version of your code that does function though:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;

for my $num (2..10) {
    my $divisor_count = 0;
    for my $divisor (1..$num) {
        $divisor_count++ if $num % $divisor == 0;
    }
    print "$num - $divisor_count\n"
}
```

Output:

```
2 - 2
3 - 2
4 - 3
5 - 2
6 - 4
7 - 2
8 - 4
9 - 3
10 - 4
```